# React redirect issue using props.history.push

Tags: testing

I met an issue in React trying to redirect using:

```
this.props.history.push('/page')
```

Do you know the solution of this problem?

thanks

Comment: So what's the issue that you have? is it an unexpected behaviour? is the redirect not working? is it not redirecting to the page you want? What react-router version are you using? which react version are you using? is there any more code that you could show us so that the issue is clear for everyone? Please think of all of these suggestion before you add a question to SO, as this is obviously not helpful at all, it cannot be reproduced, there is no context, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was from router where I erased default router property.